# Long delay to load PHP in IIS over fileshare

Tags: php, iis, unc

I have a new IIS 10 / Server 2019 server, which uses a SMB file share for app data.  My problem is, for PHP sites there is a delay of about 2 minutes and 15 seconds for a simple "hello world" website to start.  Even stranger, it does it on all sites with PHP 7.x, but not on 5.x unless it's a more complicated site like Mediawiki.  It also only does it when loaded over the fileshare, which is otherwise quick to access.  Once loaded the first time it runs quickly for about 3 min until whatever loaded process has to reload from scratch again.  Using the error log, I can see that PHP loads the ini instantly and will complain about formatting errors and such right away, but the first line of a php page does not load until the last second.  PHP xdebug also doesn't seem to note anything until the last second of loading.

It certainly seems like something is trying to resolve and timing out, but using //192.168.1.x doesn't work any better than //fileshare.  I've poured through the php.ini looking for a culprit but can't find it.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

The main settings I've messed with are the ones below with different combinations and ways of writing the path.

```
cgi.force_redirect = 0
cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
fastcgi.impersonate = 1
fastcgi.logging = 0
track_errors = Off

soap.wsdl_cache_dir = C:\inetpub\php_temp
error_log = "C:\inetpub\php_errors\php_error73.txt"
upload_tmp_dir = C:\inetpub\php_temp
sys_temp_dir = C:\inetpub\php_temp
session.save_path = C:\inetpub\php_temp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to trace it down to two odd culprits.

The main time out issue was:

```
user_ini.filename =
```

By default it's commented out in php.ini, so removing the semi colon disabled that feature which must have had trouble searching for ini files on the file share.

Second issue on 5.x seemed to be related to having the old mysql plugin enabled.  Leaving it enabled didn't seem to matter on local disk, but having it enabled caused issues on the file share.  I'm using mysqli in code, so no problem disabling it for me.